# How to run ASP.NET Core MVC with MDF localDb as a Docker container

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a project (ASP.NET Core MVC) which uses the database as MDF file localDb which is located in the project.
I want to create a Docker(linux) image for this project which includes the database MDF file as well.
So, If I run the image using a container it will work as a normal web application.
Is there any ways to achieve this requirement?

The solution structure

[image]

Comment: Do you mean not to package the entire project into a mirror deployment using docker, but to package and deploy the MDF localDb separately?

Comment: @Chaodeng No, I need to run the entire project using Docker without any issues.